# Ignore dash '-' in search Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I would like to ignore dashes in search while indexing and searching.
Ex. Client want to find HD-123 product, but he usually type "H123" in search field (but sometimes he can enter name correctly and search engine should also find result in this case).

I tried to override SearchCore::sanitize method, but it doesn't work for me.

```
    $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8');
    + $string = strtr($string, '-', '');
```

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ?

```
$string = html_entity_decode(str_replace('-', '', $string), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

or

```
$string = str_replace('-', '', html_entity_decode($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8'));
```

Depends on your process I guess